# Present UIAlertController in UITableViewCell on Presented View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uialertcontroller

I want to show `UIAlertController` from `UITableViewCell` class.

While searching I found that `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present` doing this will display it.

Which works in the case if the opened `ViewController` is under `NavigationController` because my `rootViewController` is a `NavigationController` and the view under which the `cell` is being presented.

So how can I present `UIAlertController` in `UITableViewCell` which is presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the `delegate` pattern.

Create a `protocol` implemented by your controller and assign a `weak` reference from this controller to your cell.

then use something like `cell.delegate.didPerformAction()`

The cell is a `View`, and it should not be responsible for presenting anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make a variable in cell Class, and you have to assign those class to that variable which implements cell.

then in cell on any action you just call alert like code below:

```
var fromViewController : UIViewController?

@IBAction func accessoryBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "It's Alert From Cell", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)

    fromViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```