# Reusing parts of Table View Cell in different controllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a table view cell that has a button which, when clicked, shows an action view.

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081979/6724161) saying that the logic to show the action view should be handled in the controller.

The problem is that I use these table view cells in several different controllers and it seems counterintuitive to copy and paste the action view logic into each controller where the table view cells exist, especially considering the maintenance required.

So my question is, what is the best approach to handling this? Is there a way that I can handle all of the action view logic in a single place, and refer the controllers to that code?

Comment: Could you show "the logic to show the action view"? What is it that you don't want to duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Have the action for click in tableview cell and pass a variable in cellforrow  so you know from which screen you are coming and accordingly handle the click.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : RiderCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "RiderCell") as! RiderCell
    cell.UpdateCell(from:"Profile")
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell as RiderCell
}
```

in you table cell

```
import UIKit

class RiderCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func UpdateCell(from:String){
    //manage click here
}

}
```